# Adding Ping Feature To A Windows Service

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-services, ping

For some scheduled tasks i had developed a Windows Service and started at a server. But these tasks are important for us and we have to monitor service in case of any troubleshoot we have to restart or take action if required.

Currently we are using [Argus](http://argus.tcp4me.com/) for monitoring servers or systems; so i want to add my service in monitor list in Argus. In my opinion ping will be enough for it, but i don't know how to add ping feature my service?

I think, i need to open a port using socket. But then? How should i answer echo request? "Pong" or "OK"

Comment: Are you want to check internet connection?

Comment: No i just want to monitor service status, running or stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my [article 'Observing Applications via Heartbeat' on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8349/Observing-Applications-via-Heartbeat) will help you.

But for your needs you have to change the behaviour a little bit. Your Service should wait for a request sent by UDP (or TCP, what you prefer) from Argus and send the current Status (the 'heartbeat') back to Argus. Argus will compare the response with the expected one and send an alarm if the status was wrong or nothing was received.

Ping (ICMP echo) would only check if the Server is available (reachable via IP).

Comment: i am checking your suggestion then if it suits my case i will accept your answer.

Comment: i checked example but i couldn't make clear something. How can make possible to play Argus Client role. Argus is a linux based system and we couldn't make Argus listen a port or wait a 'hearbeat' everyminute.

Comment: I had a little deeper look on Argus. It looks like a request/response pattern is needed. I was also confused myself about client and server in my answer. I will update my answer...

Answer (score 0):

please look at the [ServiceController Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28VS.80%29.aspx)

**Example:**

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(SERVICENAME);

switch (sc.Status)
{
    case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
        return "Running";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
        return "Stopped";
    case ServiceControllerStatus.Paused:
        return "Paused";
    default:
        return "Status Changing";
}
```

Comment: I think this will note be suit because i want to monitor my service from another system (in our situaion this is Argus). So i have no chance to write a piece of code and check my service is still alive. As i know argus can ping my service or check another thing about my service to learn its state. So i should add a feature to my service to tell its status.